# Location not printing to console (Swift + Xcode 7 + iOS 9)

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, core-location, ios9

I recently updated to xCode 7 which uses iOS 9 and when I run the following app, the location is supposed to print to the console but that's not happening.

The app will build successfully, the map displays, but the location data doesn't print. Even if the move the map, it still doesn't print.

The code should be correct, i've imported all of the necessary frameworks and set both the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription & NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in the Info.plist file along w/ their values.

Below is the code:

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Maps iOS9
//
//  Created by Alex Ngounou on 9/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Alex Ngounou. All rights reserved.

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {    

@IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() // starts accessing the user's position


    // 18.328278, -65.318353 Playa Flamenco
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 18.328278
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -65.318353

    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let longDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "Playa de Flamenco"
    annotation.subtitle = "Culebra Island"
    myMap.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action:")
    uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0

    myMap.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)
}

func action(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    // touchpoint
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.myMap)

    // touchpoint to location
    let newLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = myMap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.myMap)

    // annotation
    let newAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    newAnnotation.coordinate = newLocation
    newAnnotation.title = "New Poing"
    newAnnotation.subtitle = "added via user's touch"
    myMap.addAnnotation(newAnnotation)
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(locations)
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this code snippet:

```
// Location Manager helper stuff
func initLocationManager() {

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.locationServicesEnabled

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}

// Location Manager Delegate stuff
// If failed
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if (error) {
       print(error)
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: AnyObject[]!) {
        println("locations = \(locations)")
}

// authorization status
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        var shouldIAllow = false

        switch status {
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
            locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
            locationStatus = "Status not determined"
        default:
            locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
            shouldIAllow = true
        }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
        if (shouldIAllow == true) {
            NSLog("Location to Allowed")
            // Start location services
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Debug/Location" of my iOS simulator wasn't set correctly. Once I changed this to "City Bicycle Ride", everything's good!

Thanks for the help!